# RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()) in fragments not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I have this problem and i know there are similar questions with answers. But none helped me and I'm almost losing it. I'm trying to build an app making use of gson, wordpress api, fragments and volley. Each fragment has the request. But at the point
RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()) in each fragment there is a problem

My Tab1 fragment class

```
 public class Tab1 extends Fragment {


        String url = "http://absradiotv.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&fields=id,title,featured_image_url";


        List<Object> list;
        Gson gson;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        ListView postList;
        Map<String,Object> mapPost;

        Map<String,Object> mapTitle;

        int postID;
        String postTitle[];
        String postType[];
        String postFeaturedMedia[];




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyProgressTheme);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
            postList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postList);

            progressDialog.setMessage(" ");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    gson = new Gson();
                    list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
                    postTitle = new String[list.size()];
                    postType = new String[list.size()];
                    postFeaturedMedia = new String[list.size()];

                      ArrayList<String>listt = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                        mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(i);


                        mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                        postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                        postType[i] = (String) mapPost.get("type");

                        postFeaturedMedia[i] = (String) mapPost.get("featured_image_url");

                        listt.add(postTitle[i]);
                        listt.add(postType[i]);

                        listt.add(postFeaturedMedia[i]);

                    }

    //Here I tried to populate listview with id postList

                     postList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listt));


                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {






                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! An error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

//I added a check to test if getActivity returns null, but it doesnt

                 if(getActivity() != null) {
                     RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                     rQueue.add(request);
                 }
            else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A big null issue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }


            return rootView;
        }       

    }
```

This is my PagerAdapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("LATEST"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("POLITICS"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("STATE"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer,toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    }
```

Comment: Does the app crash?

Comment: No. It just return the error through Toast. "an error occured'

Comment: Please do not Toast the error message. Use `Log.e("TAG", "Error ", volleyError.getMessage());` and [edit] the question post the error log here.

Comment: Please post the error. The error could be basic such as not providing the permissions. But, unless you post the error, we cannot determine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've fixed it! I didn't add internet permissions in my manifest. It just escaped my mind!  To think I've been on this for three days!